# Чудеса С++

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, c++

```
int i = 0;
while (i < size)        //size - число строк в файле словаря
{
    fgets(buff, 4096, v);
    cutstring(buff);
    bigtosmall(buff);
    delete_multiple_zeros(buff);
    mas2[i] = buff;     //mas2 у нас char **mas2 = new char*[size];
    printf("%d %sn", i, mas2[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Выводит:

> `0 аангич
> 1 абажур
> 2 абака
> 3 аббатисса
> 4 аббатский
> 5 аббатство
> 6 аббат
> 7 абдикация
> 8 аберрация
> 9 абзац
> 10 аблегация
> 11 абонемент
> 12 абонент
> 13 абонирование
> 14 абонировать
> 15 абордаж
> 16 абордировать
> 17 аборигены`

Тут же, строчкой ниже, пишу:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d %sn", i, mas2[i]);
}
```

Выводит:

> `0 аборигены
> 1 аборигены
> 2 аборигены
> 3 аборигены
> 4 аборигены
> 5 аборигены
> 6 аборигены
> 7 аборигены
> 8 аборигены
> 9 аборигены
> 10 аборигены
> 11 аборигены
> 12 аборигены
> 13 аборигены
> 14 аборигены
> 15 аборигены
> 16 аборигены
> 17 аборигены`

С массивом указателей никаких манипуляций не проводил. Как??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Напишите mas2[i] = strdup(buff); и глядите на весь список.

У Вас адрес буфера не менялся, в нем вегда последняя прочитанная строка и все элементы mas[] указывают на нее.

Comment: mas - это массив указателей, не символов.

Comment: О, со Strdup() заработало! Да вы просто волшебник какой-то! Откуда знали-то про эту фичу?